# Lists forming figures

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to make a list whose elements form a disc when formatted.

For example, this list forms a triangle when formatted

```
{
  {1,2}, 
  {{1,2}, {1,2}}, 
  {{1,2}, {1,2}, {1,2}} 
  }//MatrixForm
```

But also, I would like manipulate the size of the list.

How can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[DiskMatrix[10], 0, {2}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Since "when formatted" is vague, you could also use `ArrayPlot`, i.e., `DiskMatrix[100] // ArrayPlot`